# How can I use python to calculate very large numbers?

Tags: python, fibonacci

Like, really, really large numbers..
I'm trying out a variation of the fiboncci series (most significant variation being it squares each term before feeding it in again, although there are a few other modifications as well.), and I need to obtain a particular term whose value is too large for python to handle. I'm talking like well over a thousand digits, probably more. The program just starts and does nothing at all.
Is there any way I can use python to print such massive numbers, or can it be done with JavaScript (preferred) or any other language?

Program in question:

```
g=[0 for y in range(31)]
g[0]=0
g[1]=1
for x in range(2,31):
    g[x]=pow((g[x-1]+g[x-2]),2)
print(g[30])
```

Comment: Python integers are only limited by the memory you can allocate to the Python process. My machine can easily handle integers with 100k digits. 1 million digits still works but becomes noticeably slower.

Comment: Python can handle numbers of any size just fine, as long as you have the memory for them. Printing them takes a long while, though

Comment: JavaScript, on the other hand, cannot handle arbitrary-size integers because all numbers are floating point (double) values.

Comment: Is there a way I can make the process faster? Like writing it into a file instead of printing or something?
My processor is 2.5Ghz with 4GB RAM, but I've been waiting for over 10 minutes, no sign of the program printing anything.

Comment: Your program fails because it has a bug, not because Python can't handle thousand-digit numbers. A rule of thumb when programming is that, given the choice between a problem with the program you just hacked together and a problem with a codebase that thousands or millions of people have been using for years, it's probably the former.

Comment: If you want us to fix your program, you will have to show it to us, the same way you have to actually bring your car to a mechanic if you want them to fix it.

Comment: Program added now. Thinking about it again, it is probably a LOT more than a thousand digits.

Comment: Assuming that squaring a number tends to approximately double its number of digits, I'd expect your final value to have about two billion digits. That seems like it's pushing it even for language with unlimited precision integers.

Answer (score 0):

your program does nothing because it has probably consumed all the memory. As far as python, it can handle very large numbers. Check this link:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/